# How do I get my attribute filter to work?

Tags: php, woocommerce, attributes

I am using woocommerce and using a attribute filter to be able to filter my products by their attributes. For example I want to filter paint by their 10litre attribute. I have no clue how to get this to work could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, it worked for us.

```
add_filter ('yith_wcan_use_wp_the_query_object', '__return_true');
```

Let me know if that is okay.